# Runtime errors in C++ implementation of quicksort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am writing an implementation of quicksort to brush up on my C++ skills, but am running into an error that is stumping me. The algorithm seems to be working fine about 25% of the time, but I keep running into the errors the other 75% of the time, where the program reports either a segmentation fault or stack overflow.  If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

#define size 20

void printSet(int* set);
int* quicksort(int* set, int l);
int* concat(int* less, int countL, int* greater, int countG);

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int* set;
    set = new int[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        set[i]=rand()%200;
    printSet(set);
    set = quicksort(set, size);
    printSet(set);
    delete set;
    int i;
    cin>> i;
    return 0;
}

int* quicksort(int* set, int l)
{
    //cout<<"QS\n";
    if (l <= 1)
        return set;
    int*      less = new int[l];
    int*   greater = new int[l];
    int pivotIndex = rand() % l, 
          pivotVal = set[pivotIndex],
            countL = 0,
            countG = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if (set[i] < pivotVal)
            less[countL++]=set[i];
        else
            greater[countG++]=set[i];
    }
    set = concat(quicksort(less, countL), countL, quicksort(greater, countG), countG);

    return set;
}

int* concat(int* less, int countL, int* greater, int countG)
{
    //cout<<"concat\n";
    int* set;
    set = new int[size];

    int i;

    for(i=0; i<countL; i++)
        set[i]=less[i];
    for(int j=0; j<countG; j++)
        set[i+j]=greater[j];

    return set;
}

void printSet(int* set)
{
    cout<<"******************\nPrinting Set\n";
    for(int i=0; i< size; i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<": "<<set[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does the error say?

Comment: What's the error? Try stepping through it with a debugger.

Comment: You also have a memory leak in your `quicksort` function, and also in the `concat` function.

Comment: also your less and greater arrays are never being deleted. On a large data set this could leak a lot of memory. Edit: beaten to it

Comment: I just edited the question to include what errors were getting reported (I ran it on my machine a few times).  Hope this clarifies things!

Comment: @Luke: Not related to your question, but it is recommended to implement quicksort without allocating any memory. You should be able to reorder your array 'in place' by just swapping elements.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that one of your errors is in this line in main:

```
delete set;
```

The problem here is that `set` is an array allocated with `new[]`.  To free its memory, you need to delete it with a matching call to `delete[]`.  This can be fixed by rewriting the line as

```
delete[] set;
```

Additionally, your code has the chance to infinitely recurse in some cases.  In particular, suppose that you try sorting a list that's two copies of 0.  In that case, consider what this code will do:

```
for(int i=0; i<l; i++)
{
    if (set[i] < pivotVal)
        less[countL++]=set[i];
    else
        greater[countG++]=set[i];
}
set = concat(quicksort(less, countL), countL, quicksort(greater, countG), countG);
```

Since your pivot element is 0 (it's the only choice!), you'll iterate across the array and put both of the 0's in the array into `greater`.  Consequently, when you recursively invoke `quicksort` on `greater`, you'll end up recursively trying to sort the exact same range that you started with, leading to infinite recursion.

To fix this, try updating your code so that you partition into three groups - elements less than the pivot, elements greater than the pivot, and elements equal to the pivot.  You would still recurse on the less and greater ranges, but you wouldn't recursively invoke yourself on the equal values.  This would ensure that the recursion always is invoked on smaller ranges than what you started with.

Finally, as others have pointed out, your current implementation leaks a **lot** of memory because you never free any of the temporary arrays you construct.  To avoid this, consider replacing your use of raw arrays with `std::vector`, which does its own memory management and won't leak any memory.  Plus, it makes it substantially easier to split the array into regions, since you can just use `push_back` to append the elements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I compiled the code and he was getting a stack overflow because of exactly what you describe. +1

Comment: @Seth Carnegie- Yeah, I ran it with gdb and valgrind to find these errors.  I hope I caught everything!

Comment: So *that's* why the OP didn't feel it was necessary to post what the error message was.

Comment: @Luke- Glad to help out!  If this answers your question, be sure to mark the answer accepted to mark the question resolved.